# SOLR: Need to perform a filter query for documents with a field value and documents with out the field itself

Tags: solr

I need to filter for documents that have a specific value for a field and all documents which do not have the field :

```
fq":"((state:"CA") OR NOT(state:*))"
```

when I execute each subcomponent separately it gives results however when I execute them together I am getting 0 documents found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subtract the `NOT` from something.

```
fq=state:CA OR (*:* NOT state:[* TO *])
```

So either it's in the set denoted by `state:CA`, or it's in the set denoted by all documents, minus those that have a value in the field. You can't just say "minus those that have a value in the field", since there is nothing to subtract from (small nitpick: Solr automagically adds the whole set to purely negative queries, so  `q=-state:[* TO *]` would work - but not when you add the boolean operators).